# Error: tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 187, 'message': 'Status is a duplicate.'}] - How do I stop getting duplicated tweet Id?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have created a twitter bot with tweepy.

Here are the functions of this bot:

1. Search for keyword.
2. Retweet.
3. Reply with standard message.

My problem:

I keep running into duplicate tweets and the program stops.

What this error is **not**:

Twitter is not stopping me from replying with the same message.

What I noticed is that I keep getting the same user id. I have tried many methods to avoid this but they do not work as indented or work for a few moments until they stop working, because of this I have not added any of the methods to this code sample as the result is absolutely the same with different variations.

Questions:

1. How do I stop getting duplicated tweet ids?
2. Is there a better method than using api.search such as StreamListener? If so how?
3. How do I get the newest tweets instead of random tweets?

Notice that all three questions are related to the original concept of removing duplicates.

Full code:

```
import tweepy
import time 

consumer_key = 'MYKEY'
consumer_secret = 'MYSECRET'    
key =  'KEY'
secret =  'SECRET'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

tweetNumber = 20    
q = "MY SEARCH"

tweets = list(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, tweet_mode='extended').items(tweetNumber))

def crashBot():    

    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
            
        try:          
                                       
                if q in tweet.full_text.lower():
                    print(str(tweet.id) + '-' + tweet.full_text)
                    api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " MY MESSAGE", tweet.id)
                    api.retweet(tweet.id)                                        
                    print("done!")                
                    time.sleep(30)            
        except tweepy.tweepyError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            time.sleep(30)
            
while True:
    crashBot()    
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: I suggest making different questions for each question of yours. Each post should be specific, and some of the questions you're asking for should definitely be asked separately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will be making a new question soon.

Answer (score 3):

```
tweets = list(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, tweet_mode='extended').items(tweetNumber))
```

Since this line only executes once, its contents will never change. So when `crashBot` runs for the second time, it will reply to the same tweets that it already replied to the first time.

One possible solution is to repopulate the list in between calls to `crashBot`.

```
while True:
    tweets = list(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, tweet_mode='extended').items(tweetNumber))
    crashBot()    
    time.sleep(30)
```

---

You could also ensure you don't reply to the same tweet more than once by keeping a set of all the tweet ids that you've seen already.

```
tweetNumber = 20    
q = "MY SEARCH"
seen = set()

def crashBot():    
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        try:          
            if tweet.id in seen:
                print("Skipping", tweet.id, "because we already replied to it")
                continue
            if q in tweet.full_text.lower():
                seen.add(tweet.id)
                #rest of code continues as before
```